# Append to body appends to iframe's body too

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function append_data(st_data) {
    $(st_data).appendTo('body');
}
```

I'm trying to add some html data after body, but also the data appends to iframe's body too.

I tried to solve it like that

```
$(st_data).appendTo($('body').not('body body'));
```

But it didn't help.

I try to create userscript, the dummy page i've created works normal, doesn't add to iframe my data. But not in http://pikabu.ru/story/ayfon_2384476 where I try to use my script, facebook iframe.

If I append to body in the link below from dev tools console, it doesn't add to iframe. But it does with the userscript.

The script - http://jsfiddle.net/thGH5/

Solved it.

I use Tampermonkey extension to run the userscript, I have to add @noframes tag to disable script run in iframe.

Comment: I find this difficult to believe. I thought you had to use `.contents()` to access something inside an iframe.

Comment: It would be greate, if you could post a _minimal_ reproduceable code snippet to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I use Tampermonkey extension to run the userscript, I have to add @noframes tag to disable script run in iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Try appending to first match, which should be the main body

```
$('body').first()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the body element instead of using a selector:

```
$(st_data).appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: iframe have document too

Comment: @RaShe: Yes, but that is an object reference, not a selector. When you use `document` you get only a reference to a single object which is the document for the current page, not a collection of all document objects.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$('body:first').append($(st_data));
```

how about this one?

```
$('</body>').append($(st_data));
```

Comment: It doens't work, two bodies doesn't have commot parent

Comment: how about the other solution?

Comment: @AminJafari: The other solution creates an empty jQuery object, so the appended element doesn't end up anywhere. (At least in Firefox, other browsers may throw an error because of the incomplete HTML code.)